# How to choose search option then submit form in mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

My goal is to search employee in active directory and allow me to choose a search option in drop down.

**For example:** If I choose the `EmployeeNumber` the form with execute and search for `EmployeeNumber` that match in input box value. *-"`SamAccountName` is default search"*

**Note:**

- When I click the `EmployeeNumber` it should submit the form.
- The `SamAccountName` button is working.

[image]

**Problem:** How to use different submit or search option?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SystemPrepared", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("spq", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search..."})
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SamAccountName</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">SamAccountName</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EmployeeNumber</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GivenName</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Surname</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">EmailAddress</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enable</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">GUID</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SID</a></li>                        
        </ul>

    </div>
}
```

**What I've tried:**

```
<li><a href="?fltr=EmployeeNumber">EmployeeNumber</a></li>
```

And get the value using request query string but the problem is the form din't submit and `spq` is empty or null.

**Update:**

Requested by Stephen

```
    public ActionResult SystemPrepared(string spq)
    {
        coockieActiveDirectory2 = db.ActiveDirectory2.Where(user =>
                user.SamAccountName.Contains(spq));

        return View(coockieActiveDirectory2);
    }
```

Currently this is just what I have in controller

Comment: Not clear what your trying to do, and why are you not using a dropdownlist so you can get the selected value. If your wanting to display the results of the search criteria on the same page, use ajax to call a method, passing the parameters and then update the DOM with the result.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just copy and paste the html code from bootstrap and try to use it. my goal is to create different submit link for my search engine.

Comment: Are you wanting to display the results on the same page or redirect to another page with the results. Is using jquery an option? And what is the method that returns the results?

Comment: @StephenMuecke "display the results on the same page" Yes!, bootstrap include jquery in my `_layout` maybe?

Comment: You need to post the controller method that returns the results

Comment: @StephenMuecke Currently I only have simple query. see my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66080/discussion-between-leonel-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap control you're using isn't really designed for this task. What you'd really need is something like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><button type="submit" name="searchType" value="SamAccountName">SamAccountName</button></li>
    <li><button type="submit" name="searchType" value="EmployeeNumber">EmployeeNumber</button></li>
    <li><button type="submit" name="searchType" value="GivenName">GivenName</button></li>
    ...                      
</ul>
```

In other words, when you clicked one of the items, it would submit the form and post along with it some value for `searchType` which you could then use to do the proper type of search based on which the user clicked. However, the Bootstrap styles don't handle that scenario. That doesn't mean that you couldn't add your own styles to make it look like a regular button dropdown though.

Alternatively, if you want to stick with the default Bootstrap styles/control and don't mind using JavaScript you could do something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="searchType" id="SearchType" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="search-submit" data-search-type="SamAccountName">SamAccountName</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="search-submit" data-search-type="EmployeeNumber">EmployeeNumber</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="search-submit" data-search-type="GivenName">GivenName</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And then add some script like the following:

```
$('.search-submit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchType = $(this).data('search-type');
    $('#SearchType').val(searchType);
    $('#YourForm').submit();
});
```

In other words, you bind an event handler to your button dropdown links that sets a hidden field to the right value and then posts the form.